# Resetting CSS transitions not working (transition end problems)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div, and I want it to exhibit the following behavior:

Instantly turn solid red;
Fade out to 50% opacity over 2 seconds;
Repeat when triggered by a certain event.

This is the code I have put in a callback that gets called every ~2 seconds:

```
    currElem.style.transition = 'none';
    currElem.style.opacity = 1;
    currElem.style.transitionProperty = 'opacity';
    currElem.style.transitionDuration = '2s';
    currElem.style.opacity = 0.5;
```

However, this does not work. Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use [CSS animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations) then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest to use [CSS animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Tutorials/Using_CSS_animations) instead.

Here you go:

```css
.box {
    background-color: tomato;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    opacity: 1;

  -webkit-animation: reduce_opacity 2s linear infinite;
     -moz-animation: reduce_opacity 2s linear infinite;
       -o-animation: reduce_opacity 2s linear infinite;
          animation: reduce_opacity 2s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes reduce_opacity { from { opacity: 1; } to { opacity: 0.5; } }
   @-moz-keyframes reduce_opacity { from { opacity: 1; } to { opacity: 0.5; } }
     @-o-keyframes reduce_opacity { from { opacity: 1; } to { opacity: 0.5; } }
        @keyframes reduce_opacity { from { opacity: 1; } to { opacity: 0.5; } }
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/7pSXE/)**

The `infinite` keyword belongs to [`animation-iteration-count`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-iteration-count) property which defines the number of times an animation cycle should be played.

### Update

As you mentioned that you're triggering the repeating the animation by a JavaScript event, you can stick with `transition` and remove/add a certain class within the event handler to achieve the effect:

```css
.animate {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 2s linear;
       -moz-transition: opacity 2s linear;
        -ms-transition: opacity 2s linear;
         -o-transition: opacity 2s linear;
            transition: opacity 2s linear;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

JavaScript (jQuery version)

```javascript
$('#reset-animation').on('click', function() {
    $('.box').removeClass('animate');

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.box').addClass('animate');
    }, 100);
});
```

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/7pSXE/3/)**.

Comment: Thank you. I should clarify, I can't have this happen on a perfect loop every 2 seconds. There is an event that gets triggered in my code every ~2 seconds. When that happens I want the CSS animation to 'reset' back to solid and then fade out. Thanks! I tried using CSS animations but I am having trouble 'resetting' or 'restarting' the animation.

Comment: However, even that jsfiddle does not work on Firefox on Linux (debian7). (Which is the environment where I was having problems all along).